# HQL query for finding records with different place ids but same ammendability for comparing records

Tags: hql

I have a table called task where place id, category ids and ammendability are the columns. I call a method where I pass two place ids placeId1, placeId2.

First query fetches the ammendability list.

```
"select distinct(ammend) from Task where flag = :sactive;";
query.setParameter("sactive", "A");
```

so this will give me three records say

```
A
B
C
```

Now I want to make a query which will fetch placeId1 and placeId2, which will have same ammendability. This is done for comparing two place ids with same ammendability.

I tried the below which doesn't work.

```
from task where placeId = :placeId1 and placeId = :placeId2 where amendability = :ammend;
```

I am not getting desired results.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like HQL. You don't show your mapping, so I have to guess that there is a one-to-many join between Task and Place.

```
     select t from Task 
         join t.place p
         where p.id in (:placeId1, :placeId2) 
         and t.ammendability = :ammend
```

But this is amost certainly not what you are looking for. It's just a guess because you really have to include your domain object code and the mappings when you want to talk about Hibernate queries.

Comment: yeah there is a one-to-many mapping as you said. Thanks for the idea. Will try it and revert back.

Comment: In Task entity, a mapping is made for place entity which is many to one.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that mapping information. Stackoverflow is intended to have useful questions that will help everybody.